# CSS: Trigger styling for the sibling

Tags: html, css

So I have an input field and a button like this:

```
<span class="btn-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="mytextfield">
    <button type="submit" id="mysubmitbutton">Go</button>
</span>
```

What I want is, when the user focuses on `mytextfield`, I want to add border to both `mytextfield` and `mysubmitbutton`.

I have tried this however it fails:

```
#mytextfield:focus + #mysubmitbutton{
border-color:solid 1px red;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

1. You are using the `border` shorthand syntax with the `border-color` property
2. You need to select both elements, not just the button.

Such:

```
#mytextfield:focus,
#mytextfield:focus + #mysubmitbutton{
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

Here's the fiddle to check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/za4EW/

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems:

First your html isn't correct, you need to close the `input` tag, like this:

```
<span class="btn-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="mytextfield" />
    <button type="submit" id="mysubmitbutton">Go</button>
</span>
```

And your css isn't correct, you need `border`

```
#mytextfield:focus + #mysubmitbutton{
     border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LMTmM/

Comment: Closing the input tag is optional if he is using the HTML5 doctype as its a void element http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

Comment: Closing the input tag is just wrong if he is using HTML 4.x or earlier.